# Edge browser does not open window to proper width

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

Here is a JS fiddle of it:

https://jsfiddle.net/df4tjt38/8/

```
<div>
<a href='about:blank' onclick="window.open(this.href, 'cbchat','width=300,height=570,resizable=0'); return false;">

click me
</a>
```

The width is set to 300, but the size opened is 322px.  I've seen a bunch of other SO questions about this, but they seem to relate to preview builds of Win10 or Edge.  I am running Edge 40.15063.674.0.  Is there a workaround for this, or am I doing it wrong to begin with?

Comment: This could still be a bug in edge: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/11026637/

They 'say' they fixed it... I'm not on windows so can't test it out for you

Comment: Yes, I agree - Edge has improved recently, but historically had issues with window.open(). It's still not quite cutting-edge, but I've learned to relax about  it - it's not far off nowadays and does most things right. Your alternative in Windows is IE11 which is now very solid -- but neither are as good as Chrome, especially if you're using 'contenteditable'.